# How to use Select in preact-material-components

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, preact

Im using [preact-material-components](https://github.com/prateekbh/preact-material-components) on PWA.

I want to add a Select Menu so I can do like this:

```
import { h, Component } from 'preact';
import Select from 'preact-material-components/Select';
import 'preact-material-components/Select/style.css';
```

and then

```
export default class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div class={style.home}>
                <h1>Home route</h1>

                <Select>
                    <Select.Item>Frutas y Verduras</Select.Item>
                    <Select.Item>Farmacia</Select.Item>
                    <Select.Item>Comida Rapida</Select.Item>
                    <Select.Item>Limpieza</Select.Item>
                </Select>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

But the Select Menu is not looking good at all, I can see with dev tools that the styles are being imported but it looks like something is wrong with CSS, I'm new to React so I would like to know your opinion about this code.

[image: PWA Select Menu]

Comment: Try to check this [github post](https://github.com/prateekbh/preact-material-components) to guide you on the proper usage of `preact-material-components`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If you are using this component individually, DO NOT FORGET to import 'preact-material-components/Menu/style.css' and 'preact-material-components/List/style.css'*

from https://material.preactjs.com/component/select